# FlightData missing in Transportation Data but available through WolframAlpha

Tags: curated-data, wolfram-alpha-queries

`FlightData` is listed in [Transportation Data](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/TransportationData.html) but its link does not work in *Mathematica* help or on the website reference help. It also returns a symbol-not-found error from `Definition` (`?`).

```
?FlightData
Information::notfound: Symbol FlightData not found. >>
```

However, if you ask for flight data in a `WolframAlpha` query it does return the data.

```
Association[
  WolframAlpha["American Airlines flight 234", 
   "DataRules"]][{{"FlightStatus:FlightData", 1}, "ComputableData"}]
(* "estimated to depart Miami, Florida, United States  (KMIA) at 10:33 pm ADT (today)" *)
```

Is this a bug with `FlightData`, or did some not yet implemented functions made it to the documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a documentation oversight.

The function `FlightData` is not available in *Mathematica* as of this time.